# randomForest Predict error from test set

Tags: r, random-forest

I am running into a an error with the R package of randomForest where after I split the data using Caret into training and testing, when I go to predict I run into error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(randomForestFit, type = "response", newdata =testing$GEN) 
:number of variables in newdata does not match that in the training data
```

I split the file between train and test from the exact same file. There are no N/A or missing values in any of the data. Below is my full code, but I do not think there is an error there. I am at a loss as to why this error is occurring. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(caret)
require(foreign)

set.seed(825)
data <- read.spss("C:/MODEL_SAMPLE.sav",use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(data$GEN, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
training <- data[inTraining, ]
testing <- data[-inTraining, ]


library(randomForest)
library(foreach)

start.time <- Sys.time()

randomForestFit <- foreach(ntree=rep(63, 8), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest')          
                    %dopar% randomForest(training[-201],
                                         training$GEN, 
                                         mtry = 40, 
                                         ntree=ntree,  
                                         verbose = TRUE, 
                                         importance = TRUE, 
                                         keep.forest=TRUE, 
                                         do.trace = TRUE)

randomForestFit

predict = predict(randomForestFit, type="response", newdata=testing$GEN)

stopCluster(cl)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the data, its hard for anyone to say what the problem is exactly.

Three suggestions:

First, check the SPSS file for stray characters in the data.

Second, check the options from read.spss are set correctly especially: *reencode = NA, use.missings =to.data.frame*. You can use the latter option to specify non numeric characters to be turned into NA.

Third, use *str(df), summary(df,useNA="if any")* and make sure your factor variables including the response are actually factors. Apply *as.numeric(as.character())* to numeric data in the data frame, this will generate NA values if there are expressions like VALUE!, #NA in the data frame.

You could also export to csv from SPSS and do the above again.

Comment: checked entire data set for N/As, VALUE! and anything missing.  Nothing came up.  All variables are numeric with the exception of the dep which is a 2 factor var (yes/no).

Comment: ok, did you try reading as csv? I had problems reading a very large SPSS file sometime ago and this worked for me. Use the options in read.csv too: stringsAsFactors =FALSE,strip.white = TRUE, na.strings = c("NA","","n/a","null") and maybe add others if necessary.

Comment: also saved it into csv and it exported/opended perfectly.  Then scanned the csv file for N/As and Values! as well as spaces...nothing

Answer (score 0):

The key is the following

```
:number of variables in newdata does not match that in the training data
```

I therefore guess that the training and test data are different, in particular the column names. Maybe it breaks at this line?

```
inTraining <- createDataPartition(data$GEN, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
```

To better understand the problem, you might have to post 3 rows of the training and test data set (with column names!).

I hope this helps!